# Microsoft OData C# WebApi Filtering or Casting Int to String

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am currently using a third party Grid control in my application that uses odata to perform server side filtering. When I fill in the search box, the filter string is meant to be applied to all fields and return only those that match.

I have two fields that I am displaying, an integer Id field and a string Name field. When the filter is applied, Odata delivers an ODataQueryOptions data type that contains a filter:

(substringof('24',tolower(Id))) or (substringof('24',tolower(Name)))

The expected result is to return any records that have 24 in the Id or 24 in the Name field.

Instead, this causes an exception. The exception is caused because Id is an Int field, and the string functions tolower and substring are not implemented on an integer field.

Cast does not seem to be implemented either, so I can't simply cast to int to a string.

This issue must have been a problem for many, many other people. So how do other people get around this issue?

(According to nuget, I am using v5.8.2 of Microsoft.Data.OData, and v5.7.0 of Microsoft.AspNet.Webapi.OData. My project is .net framework 4.5.2)

Answer (score 0):

As described in [casting int to string in OData raises error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456013/casting-int-to-string-in-odata-raises-error) and further explained in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541472.aspx there is no cast from `int` to `string`.

Your grid control would have to issue a correct query like this:

```
Id eq 24 or (substringof('24',tolower(Name)))
```

If you cannot change the query on the originating side, you can rewrite the ODataQueryOptions yourself, which I described in [Modifying ODataQueryOptions on the fly](https://d-fens.ch/2017/02/26/modifying-odataqueryoptions-on-the-fly/). the post basically shows you how to extract the current ODataQueryOptions and construct a new Uri from that which can be used to create new ODataQueryOptions.